# she tall, he a teacher, they at school - what will a native speaker undertand?

Tags: grammar, be

everyone! 
if a say statements like these: *she tall, he a teacher, they at school* - what will a native speaker undertand?
Will 'the time of being' be clear for a native English speaker from these statements? 
or will you get just a general idea of what is meant by these statements?
I know the correct forms, what I really would like to know is what a native speaker will hear and understand if I say so.

Comment: They'll understand that you are not a native speaker, or that you speak like Tarzan, take your choice. NOT my downvote nor my upvote.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am really sorry for my mistyping. I will try not to return to this site and fine the right one for me. I thought this the right place to ask about Egnlish. I was wrong I am sorry. Could I ask you to think about the difference between an arror, mistake and mistyping? Thank you very much again for you kind asnwer.

Comment: Now, you're making me feel guilty about my initial harsh reaction. Anyway, look to [**English Language for Learners**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), it's our sister site. I think that website would be perfect for someone who is learning English.

Comment: I'm wondering why, 16 hours after the asking, that no one has mentioned that this is an example of what is called Black English, or African American vernacular. Although it is hardly true that all Blacks speak this way, or that the only Blacks speak this way, this dialect, considered legitimate by linguists, derived from the everyday language of some undereducated and underprivileged Blacks.  This dialect routinely omits the present of to be and has a regular grammar different from standard English.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Tense_and_aspect

Answer (score 2):

Most native speakers will understand that you've omitted the present tense of the verb to be.  This is a common locution in US urban dialects, particularly in song lyrics.  Check here for *[dang she fine](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/jdash/wop.html)* (the translation to square would be "Wow! She's attractive.") and here for *[you wack](https://fashionculturemag.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/25532415.jpg?w=620)* (square:  "You're crazy.")

I had a friend who served in the army.  He reported that his drill sergeant would regard his screwups, shake his head, and say, "Man, you a idiot."  My friend had no trouble understanding the sergeant.

If the situation requires more formal speech or if you don't ordinarily use this dialect, your listeners may wonder why you're dropping the verb.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That a comma splice.

Comment: The OP's question is interesting - for, as well as what you describe, it is also an abbreviated way of speaking, a kind of speech figure designed to hammer a message home. I actually think it is a very good question.

Comment: Yes, it's a comma slice. And now I know a number of native American speakers say "She tall girl" thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It wasn't so much a comment on your sentence structure as a wiseass way of slipping in another verbless sentence.  I think American speakers would say "She a tall girl," lest they be misheard saying "She tall, girl."

Answer (score 0):

Native speakers would take these to mean **present tense**, and would view them as:

> She is tall
>
> He is a teacher
>
> They are at school

But as has been pointed out, some native English speakers would associate this with a lack of education.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted to understand.